# How to add newline to end of file.write()?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a simple python script that outputs to an `author.json` file.  The problem is that it does not include a newline at the end of the file.

What is the best way to add a newline to the end of `author.json`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

with open('input.json', 'r') as handle:
    data = json.load(handle)

output = open('author.json', 'w')

author = {}

for key, value in data.items():
    if key == 'id':
        author['id'] = value


output.write(json.dumps(author, indent=4))
```

Comment: `output.write('\n')` ? or `print(json.dumps(author, indent=4),file=output)`

Comment: Hey, what do you know =)  It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Python 3.x , you can also use `print()` function, it will add the newline for you , so instead of `output.write()` , you will do   -

```
print(json.dumps(author, indent=4),file=output)
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> with open('a.txt','w') as f:
...     print('asd',file=f)
...     print('asd1',file=f)
...     print('asd2',file=f)
```

File `a.txt` contains -

```
asd
asd1
asd2
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the end of line manually:

```
output.write('{}\n'.format(json.dumps(author, indent=4)))
```

I hope you realize that your script will only ever have the last id's value in the output; as you are overwriting the key in your loop (dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys).

So even if you have 5 `id` values in the original file, you'll only have one value in the resulting data.

Answer (score -3):

```
put.write(json.dumps("author\n", indent=4))
```

Comment: In the original question `author` is a variable, not a string.